# How do I pass in a value into a sql statement using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to make my sql statements more secure for an API that I am developing. While I know that there are ORM tools that make this easier, I am new at this and want to understand the basics, and best practices. I first created an sql statement that concatenated the values into a string. It was recommended in a previous post of mine that it would leave me vulnerable to SQL injections. I tried the recommended approach but was not successful. The question mark used as a placeholder was never replaced with the value i was trying to pass it.

Note: although related, it is not a duplicate of [[Passing a node.js parameter in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538998/passing-a-node-js-parameter-in-sql-query]). The usage and solutions are slightly different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried several ways but each time the ? was never replaced. I can see this in the console. I also logged the value of 'id' to make sure that there was a value to be passed at that level in the functions scope.

Note: this originated from the following issue: [How do I insert a value into a select statement using JavaScript, specifically when using express and postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895856/how-do-i-insert-a-value-into-a-select-statement-using-javascript-specifically-w)

This works but is not very safe...

```
    return db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${id}`);
```

None of the following worked...

```
return db.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?',['id']);
return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?',['id']);
return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?',[id]);
return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?',id);
return db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?`,id);
```

Each time the console shows the following...

```
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a node.js parameter in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538998/passing-a-node-js-parameter-in-sql-query)

Comment: Link the official documentation for `db.js`

Comment: The [docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) say you need to use `$1`, `$2` etc

Comment: @ChrisG thanks! This resolved my issue.

Comment: Note: although related, it is not a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538998/passing-a-node-js-parameter-in-sql-query].  The usage and solutions are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Usign $ as a placeholder rather than a questionmark with Node.js worked.

Example:

```
return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1',[id]);
```